# DataType(DataType.Password)] is being ignored when i am rendering a list of @Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application. and i have the following model class:-

```
public class ACCOUNTLIST
    {
        public string ACCOUNTNAME { set; get; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string PASSWORD { set; get; }


        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("PASSWORD")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPASSWORD { set; get; }

        public string NOTES { set; get; }
    }
```

where i am rendering a list of empty model classes as follow:-

```
for(int i2 = start; i2 < count ; i2++) 
{ 

<div >@Html.DisplayName("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") 
@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") 
@Html.ValidationMessage("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") 
</div>

<div >@Html.DisplayName("["+i2.ToString()+"].ConfirmPASSWORD") 
@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].ConfirmPASSWORD")
@Html.ValidationMessage("["+i2.ToString()+"].ConfirmPASSWORD")
</div>
}
```

now the the problem i am facing is that the generated fields from the @Html.Editor will not hide the text being entered using dotted circles .. so seems the `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` will not have any effect inside the `@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD) & @Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].ConfirmPASSWORD)`. and the related fields will be renders as follow:-

```
<input name="[0].ConfirmPASSWORD" class="text-box single-line valid" type="text" value="">
```

?? can anyone adivce on this please?

Comment: Because you not generating controls associated with a a model, so there are no `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` to be applied. Use `@Html.Password()` or generate your view correctly. Create a model that is `List<ACCOUNTLIST>` and add 12 empty items, then in the view `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].PASSWORD) .... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but my [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("PASSWORD")] will work well (but without client side validation, only server side validation) .. so not sure why [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("PASSWORD")] worked well (server side validation),, while [DataType(DataType.Password)] did not work?

Comment: As I stated in the first comment - your not binding to a model (just creating arbitary inputs with a `name="[#].ACCOUNTLIST"` attribute - there is no metadata that the `Editor()` method can use to add `type="password"` to the input. You should never generate form controls like that. You need to bind to your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke in my case i need to generate 5 empty sets of objects, that why i am doing it the way shown in my question.. now i do not want to use Html.Password since by defualt the Html.Password will clear its values when the view is rendered due to failed post back, while using editor or textbox will preserve the password values after a failed post back

Comment: Then read my first comment - in your controller create a `List<ACCOUNTLIST>` and populate it with 5 default `ACCOUNTLIST` and pass it to the view, then in the view - `@model List<ACCOUNTLIST>` and  use a `for` loop so that you bind to your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this view is being referenced from around 10 action methods,, so i do not want to modify the action method to create 5 default AccountList objects,, i am trying to do all these modifications inside the view itself as it will minimize working effort and future modifications.. now i define my field as follow @Html.TextBox("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD",null,new { @type="password"})  so i had a textbox with password effect.. at the same time it will preserve the value after a failed post back .. so should i be fine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113787/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-john-g).